# Plotting order of GLMeshItem and GLScatterPlotItem in interactive GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, qtopengl

I am creating a gui in python using OpenGL and PyQt5. I'm struggling to get the plotting order correct in a gui I'm making. I am trying to get 3d points to show up on top of the mesh faces, but nothing I do gets the mesh transparency to change, or adds the 3d points on top of the mesh.
[image]

Here, you can see my gui with the mesh person in white, and some red dots around the waist. I can't get them to appear on top of the mesh.

This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt  # Import Qt module for alignment
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np

def read_obj_file(file_path):
    """
    Read vertices and faces from an OBJ file.
    """
    vertices = []
    faces = []

    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            parts = line.strip().split()
            if len(parts) == 0 or parts[0] == '#':
                continue
            if parts[0] == 'v':
                vertices.append(list(map(float, parts[1:])))
            elif parts[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                for vertex in parts[1:]:
                    indices = vertex.split('/')
                    face.append(int(indices[0]) - 1)  # OBJ file indices are 1-based
                faces.append(face)

    return np.array(vertices), np.array(faces)

def triangulate_faces(faces):
    """
    Triangulate the quadrilateral faces into triangles.
    """
    triangles = []
    for face in faces:
        # Split each quadrilateral face into two triangles
        triangles.append([face[0], face[1], face[2]])
        triangles.append([face[0], face[2], face[3]])
    return np.array(triangles)


def create_mesh(vertices, faces):
 
    mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(vertexes=vertices, faces=faces, drawEdges=True)
    #how to make edge thickness bigger??
    return mesh

def plane_mesh_intersection(vertices, faces, y_plane):
    """
    Find the intersection points of a plane in the y-direction with a mesh.
    
    Args:
    - vertices (np.array): Array of mesh vertices.
    - faces (np.array): Array of mesh faces.
    - y_plane (float): Y-coordinate of the plane.
    
    Returns:
    - intersection_points (list): List of intersection points as (x, y, z) coordinates.
    """
    intersection_points = []
    
    for face in faces:
        v1, v2, v3 = vertices[face[0]], vertices[face[1]], vertices[face[2]]
        
        # Check if all vertices are on the same side of the plane
        above_plane = v1[1] >= y_plane and v2[1] >= y_plane and v3[1] >= y_plane
        below_plane = v1[1] < y_plane and v2[1] < y_plane and v3[1] < y_plane
        
        if not above_plane and not below_plane:
            # Calculate intersection points with the plane for each edge
            intersections = []
            for v_start, v_end in [(v1, v2), (v2, v3), (v3, v1)]:
                # Check if the edge crosses the plane
                if v_start[1] != v_end[1]:
                    t = (y_plane - v_start[1]) / (v_end[1] - v_start[1])
                    if 0 <= t <= 1:
                        intersection_point = (
                            v_start[0] + t * (v_end[0] - v_start[0]),
                            y_plane,
                            v_start[2] + t * (v_end[2] - v_start[2])
                        )
                        intersections.append(intersection_point)
            
            # Add intersection points to the list
            if intersections:
                intersection_points.extend(intersections)
    
    return intersection_points

def main():
    # Create a PyQtGraph application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('3D Mesh Plot')
    window.setGeometry(200, 200, 900, 700)  # Set initial window size

    # Create a central widget for displaying 3D graphics
    central_widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    central_widget.setLayout(layout)
    window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    # Create a widget for displaying 3D graphics
    widget = gl.GLViewWidget()
    widget.setCameraPosition(distance=300, azimuth=-90, elevation=90)

    layout.addWidget(widget)

    # Read vertices and faces from OBJ file
    vertices, faces = read_obj_file('Female.obj')

    # Triangulate the faces
    faces = triangulate_faces(faces)

    # Calculate the center of the mesh
    center = vertices.mean(axis=0)

    # Translate the mesh to center it at the origin
    vertices -= center
    
    # Create the mesh object
    mesh = create_mesh(vertices, faces)
    mesh.setGLOptions('translucent')

    # Add the mesh to the widget
    widget.addItem(mesh)
    
    
    #calculate 
    plane = 0
    test = plane_mesh_intersection(vertices, faces, plane)
    
    # Add intersection points to the widget as spheres
    for point in test:
        sphere = gl.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=np.array([point]), color=(1, 0, 0, 1), size=10)
        widget.addItem(sphere)
    

    # Create a QWidget for displaying text boxes
    text_widget = QWidget()
    text_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    text_widget.setLayout(text_layout)
    layout.addWidget(text_widget)
    layout.setStretch(0, 3)  # Set stretch factor for the 3D graphics widget
    layout.setStretch(1, 1)  # Set stretch factor for the text widget
    
    Labels = ["Height", "Weight", "Chest", "Waist", "Hips"]
    Measurements = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    # Add multiple QLabel widgets with gray backgrounds
    for i in range(5):  # Change the range according to the number of text boxes you want
        label = QLabel(Labels[i] + " : " + str(Measurements[i]))
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)  # Center the text horizontally and vertically
        label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;")
        text_layout.addWidget(label)
        
    # Start the application event loop
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone, but I was able to kind of fix this by modifying the shading of the mesh.

```
def create_mesh(vertices, faces):
 
    mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(vertexes=vertices, faces=faces, drawEdges=True)
    #how to make edge thickness bigger??
    
    shader = 'shaded'  # Possible values: 'normalColor', 'edgeHilight', 'heightColor', 'colored'
    mesh.setShader(shader)
    
    return mesh
```

[See the mesh and 3D points here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bl7E.png)